# Linked Posts API (new) sample code is not working

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to use the new LinkedIn Posts API to make a post. I started by trying to duplicate the curl sample code at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/posts-api?view=li-lms-2022-06&tabs=curl#text-only-post-creation-sample-request

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.linkedin.com/rest/posts \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer {INSERT_TOKEN}' \
-H 'X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0' \
-H 'LinkedIn-Version: {version number in the format YYYYMM}' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "author": "urn:li:organization:5515715",
  "commentary": "Sample text Post",
  "visibility": "PUBLIC",
  "distribution": {
    "feedDistribution": "NONE",
    "targetEntities": [],
    "thirdPartyDistributionChannels": []
  },
  "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
  "isReshareDisabledByAuthor": false
}'
```

I replaced the bearer token with my own, and changed the author to `urn:li:person:{my id}`

I get the following error suggesting that I a have asked for a specific adContext:

```
{"errorDetailType":"com.linkedin.common.error.BadRequest","code":"MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELD_FOR_DSC","message":"Field /adContext/dscAdAccount is required when the post is a Direct Sponsored Content, but missing in the request","errorDetails":{"inputErrors":[{"description":"Field /adContext/dscAdAccount is required when the post is a Direct Sponsored Content, but missing in the request","input":{"inputPath":{"fieldPath":"/adContext/dscAdAccount"}},"code":"MISSING_REQUIRED_FIELD_FOR_DSC"}]},"status":400}
```

In the hope that that was the default, I added an adContext `"adContext": {"isDsc": False}`

and that gave me `{"errorDetailType":"com.linkedin.common.error.BadRequest","code":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","message":"ReadOnly field present in a create request","errorDetails":{"inputErrors":[{"description":"ReadOnly field present in a create request","input":{"inputPath":{"fieldPath":"/adContext/isDsc"}},"code":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY"}]},"status":400}`

I also tried a blank adContext.

Has anyone had any luck using this API, or can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you found anything for this? I'm facing this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the same error; changing

```
"feedDistribution": "NONE",
```

to

```
"feedDistribution": "MAIN_FEED",
```

worked for me.

If anyone knows what that means, let us know :-)